# Compilation failure during install

Tags: maven, tycho

During install I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:0.16.0:compile (default-compile) on project com.iwaysoftware.eclipse.common: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/akravets/dev/workspaces/trunk/com.iwaysoftware.eclipse.common/src/com/iwaysoftware/eclipse/common/model/BaseTreeNode.java:[317,0]
[ERROR] public int getChildIndex(ITreeNode child) {
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method getChildIndex(ITreeNode) of type BaseTreeNode must override a superclass method
[ERROR] /home/akravets/dev/workspaces/trunk/com.iwaysoftware.eclipse.common/src/com/iwaysoftware/eclipse/common/util/NamespaceUpdater.java:[13,0]
[ERROR] public boolean visit(IResourceDelta delta) throws CoreException {
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method visit(IResourceDelta) of type NamespaceUpdater must override a superclass method
```

What I don't understand is that in Eclipse workspace I don't see these errors. And the very first time I ran install all plugins compiled fine. Here is my parent POM http://pastebin.com/U8J180J0

Comment: So it seems that it's because of @Override annotations I get these errors. Any way to suppress these without removing the annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some of the projects are set to 1.5 and I am compiling against 1.6: [@Override compile error, implementing an interface (eclipse jdk1.6.0_23 linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995780/override-compile-error-implementing-an-interface-eclipse-jdk1-6-0-23-linux)

Also need to add to parent POM

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
  <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.16.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.6</source>
    <target>1.6</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```